# How to Run a Python Program Built by dpkg-buildpackage Using dh-virtualenv?

Tags: python, debian, virtualenv, dpkg

[dh-virtualenv](https://dh-virtualenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/info.html) is a tool that aims to combine Debian packaging with self-contained virtualenv based Python deployments...

I was able to successfully build a python package (called my-project.deb) by dpkg-buildpackage Using dh-virtualenv and then installed it using "dpkg -i my-project.deb". Now, the "/opt/my-project" is created with a self-contained virtual environment but I do not know how to run my program. My program entry point file name is "main.py" but do not see this file anywhere in the path above

Now, my question is how to run my program which successfully built using [dh-virtualenv](https://dh-virtualenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/info.html)? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two different ways:

- Using the source code:

  /opt/my-project/bin/python /opt/my-project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/my-project/main.py
- Via the Virtual Environment and the Python Shell:

  source /opt/my-project/bin/activate

  python

  from my-project import main

  main.main()